# How to generate views from migrations in Laravel?

Tags: crud, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

I am using **Laravel 5.4** and the package [migrations-generator](https://packagist.org/packages/xethron/migrations-generator) that generates migrations.

So I have the migrations and now I need to generate the views automatically using Artisan. I tried it on **Symfony** and it was so easy but I can't do it with Laravel.

Here is an example of a migration file called **2017_07_01_202030_create_personas_table.php** for persons.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreatePersonasTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('personas', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->string('nombre', 100);
            $table->dateTime('fecha_de_nacimiento');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('personas');
    }

}
```

I tried more than eight packages to resolve my problem: generate model, views and controller from a table (on Laravel 5.4) but they don't work. Else I will use the Yii Framework that works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:controller MyController -r --model=MyModel
```

It will generate Controller with REST function inside them. & also create model if its not created.

You can also use below command to generate migration while creating Model

```
php artisan make:Model MyModel --migration
```

& For manage views you can use this. I haven't used it yet but come to see this package suggest by many time.

https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't use the migrations. I need to use migrations to generate the models, views and controllers. The data of my database is only in the migrations folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to generate migration and views in a single artisan command, just install & use this popular package from Jeffrey Way https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended. Just follow the steps from that page.